# how to submit(pass) loop values in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
<form name="pay" action="next.php" method="post">
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><b>Contract Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="project_name" value="<?php echo "$row[project_name]"; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="alt" ><b> Pay</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="base_salary" id="base_salary" size=10 value="<?php echo "$row[project_name]"; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>

<tr><td class="alt" ><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Compute"/></td></tr>
</form>
```

How to submit this `while` loop values to next.php page?

Comment: The values in the form when the user presses submit are sent to next.php to be processed.On that page you do the connection the while loop etc.

Comment: And you do not need a new row to close PHP `<tr><?php } ?></tr>` --> `<?php } ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Change `project_name` to `project_name[]` and `base_salary` to `base_salary[]`

So your form has the two inputs like this,

```
<input type="text" name="project_name[]" value="<?php echo "$row[project_name]"; ?>

<input type="text" name="base_salary[]" id="base_salary" size=10 value="<?php echo "$row[project_name]"; ?>">
```

**Step 2:** In your next.php

```
$project_name=$_POST['project_name'];

$base_salary=$_POST['base_salary'];

foreach( $project_name as $key => $project )
{
  echo "The project name is $project and the base salary is $base_salary[$key]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the input name from `name="project_name"` to `name="project_name[]"`

on the next php page

```
$project_name = $_POST['project_name'];
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($project_name);$i++) 
{
// $project_name[$i]//  will give one value at a time for the textbox
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot the base_salary input here.

Comment: thanks..thats right...But I was just trying to make the point...

Comment: I could understand that. Cheers :)